# The object's constructor property is omitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined a simple JavaScript class

```
function Demo(a,b){
         this.a=a;
         this.b=b;
}

//and Demo objects inherit from the prototype
Demo.prototype = {
     toString : function() { return this.a + " " + this.b ; }
}

//usage
var d = new Demo("Hello","world");
console.log(d);
```

But the instances do not have constructor property. Why is that? I mean when I do this

```
console.log(d.constructor) //function Object() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Did you mean `new Demo("Hello","world")`?

Comment: You've got some bad syntax there - the `toString` should be `toString: ` instead of `toString = ` - or `Demo.prototype.toString = function() { ... };` would be more correct, rather than reassigning `prototype` to a whole new object.

Comment: If you want this to output "hello world" you would need to use d.toString()

Comment: My bad... the syntax error were just because I was looking for some logical query. See the updated question.

Comment: Well, you replaced the original object that has the original `.constructor` property, so why are you surprised that it's no longer there?

Comment: You never assigned a constructor to the instance, so why would you expect it to have changed from what's assigned to `Object.prototype.constructor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the constructor property to point to `Demo`, then you need to assign it:

```
function Demo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

Demo.prototype = {
     constructor: Demo,
     toString: function () {
         return this.a + ' ' + this.b;
     }
};

var d = new Demo('Hello', 'world');
console.log(d.constructor);
```

This will print the following:

```
function Demo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

If you want `d` to be treated as a string, then you need to cast it:

```
console.log('' + d); //prints 'Hello world';
```

Comment: That worked. I tried. But will you explain, is it getting replaced or omitted , if i do not assign it.

Comment: `constructor` is just a property like any other. If you don't assign it, access will flow up the prototype chain until it finds something (which happens at `Object.prototype.constructor`). If it doesn't find a value, `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

An object literal (the curly braces) inherits from Object and so the constructor property will be the same as Object's unless you override it with your own value like in zzzzBov's answer. You would get the same result if you inherited directly from Object as in `Demo.prototype = new Object();`.

Inheriting from an object that inherits from `Function` gives you the constructor property you are looking for without having to define it yourself. Try this instead:

```
function DemoBase(a,b){
         this.toString=function() { return this.a + " " + this.b ; }
}

function Demo(a,b){
         this.a=a;
         this.b=b;
}
Demo.prototype = new DemoBase();

//usage
var d = new Demo("Hello","world");
console.log(d);
console.log(d.constructor)
```

Comment: Still getting 'function Function() { [native code] }' for constructor. Can you explain

Comment: I think you might have grabbed the code before I updated my answer. Can you try it again with the latest code?

Comment: Yes, I made an instance of Demo that prototypically inherits from DemoBase. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @nyxem1, I updated my answer to hopefully answer your original question as to why it was not what you were expecting.

Comment: hopefully, dats the other way round. But you did it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Demo(a,b){
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.getA = function() { return this.a };
     this.getB = function() { return this.b };
     this.concat = function() {return this.a + ' ' + this.b};
 }

  Demo.prototype.toString = function() { return this.a + ' ' + this.b ; }

  //usage
  var d = new Demo('Hello','world');
  console.log(d.concat());
  console.log(d.toString());
```

Here is a [screenshot](http://puu.sh/afD9S/cefdccff34.png) of what you are wanting:

Comment: here is a screen shot with the constructor property: http://puu.sh/afDvJ/b133d375d9.png

Comment: But i am not getting that on the console. I have already shown the output 'function Object() { [native code] } '.

Comment: copy and paste the code piece by piece like the screenshot shows and you can recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this.

```
function Demo(a,b){
     this.a=a;
     this.b=b;
}

Demo.prototype.toString = function toString() { return this.a + " " + this.b ; }

var d = new Demo('Hello','world');
console.log(d);
```

I have created a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/NEv4M/1/